# Heroku Clojure error: This ResultSet is closed

Tags: heroku, jdbc, clojure

I am getting a "This ResultSet is closed." error on new instances of my Clojure web server application on Heroku.  The error occurs on an update! operation (which is not lazy so it is not that problem).  Select statements work fine on the same database connection.

The code works on my machine :). It works on a heroku instance created some weeks ago.  It fails on newly created instances.  I have duplicated the error with a stripped down code version.

Has heroku changed recently?  I have been informed that other people saw this error when they had a problem with JDBC pools.  Could that be happening here?

This is my test code, minus the requires.

```
(defn vote-for-paper [db user-id paper-id]
(update! db :votes {:votes 1} ["user_id=? AND paper_id=?" user-id paper-id]))


(defroutes voting
(POST "/vote" [:as {db :connection}] (vote-for-paper db 1 2)))

(defn make-wrap-db [db-url]
(fn [handler]  
    (fn [req]   
        (with-db-connection [db {:connection-uri db-url}]
            (handler (assoc req :connection db))))))

(defn make-handler [db-url] 
(let [wrap-db (make-wrap-db db-url)] 
    (-> voting
        (wrap-db)
        (wrap-with-logger))))

(defn -main [& args]
(let [
        url (System/getenv "JDBC_DATABASE_URL") 
        portString (System/getenv "PORT")
        port (Integer/parseInt portString)
    ]
        (run-jetty (make-handler url) {:port port})))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are rebinding the db local variable in your defroutes.

```
(defroutes voting
(POST "/vote" [:as {db :connection}] (vote-for-paper db 1 2)))
```

Should be

```
(defroutes voting
(POST "/vote" (vote-for-paper db 1 2)))
```

Can you give that a try? I’m on mobile so that’s untested code.

Comment: That's not going to work.  db is not a local variable there, [:as {db :connection}] pulls it out of the req structure.

Comment: Ahh I see now. Yeah my suggestion isn’t going to work. What happens if you remove the wrap with logger call?  Usually the resultset error your getting comes from trying to work with a consumed resultset response, think of it as a read once object. I read you’re supposed to transfer the contents into a Clojure data structure and then manipulate that.

Comment: Also, isn’t the Heroku env variable just “DATABASE_URL”? I just shipped a Heroku app this past week and that was what I needed to use.

Comment: It failed without logging too.  Which environment variable to use looks to be context dependent, in particular this is a JDBC connection string.  This is not failing always.  There is an instance which works, so any fix for a problem that will always fail is not the correct solution.  It is not failing on the consumption of data read from the database, it is failing on the update!

Comment: Are you sure the result of `update!` is not lazy?  Try wrapping it in a `(vec ...)`

Comment: OK, I tried that, it still failed.  I suppose the not lazy comment was a red herring since I am not using the results of the update!.

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace?

Comment: Here is a pastebin link to the log of one execution of the test code https://pastebin.ca/3978589

Comment: The above is from the current version of the test code.  It includes a println of the current value of the votes.  The earlier tests were with a copy of the complete database.  This is with a cut down version created with heroku pg:psql.  The source is in pastebin here: https://pastebin.ca/3978595

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and changed my project.clj’s postgresql driver from
`[postgresql "9.3-1102.jdbc41"]`
to
`[org.postgresql/postgresql "42.2.6.jre7"]`
and the problem went away.